# Javascript querying SharePoint Date Column returning '/Date(1494460800000)/'

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010, momentjs

I've got some JavaScript which is querying a SharePoint Date Column. The format is: `DD/MM/YYYY` and the results come back fine except for the date which is coming back as pictured under Device Details.

[image: HTML results]

I'm trying to use the Moment.js library to format it but I'm not having any luck.
I think it's either this line:

```
var LifeCycleStart = item.DeviceAvailableFrom;
```

or this line I need to use the Moment formatting on:

```
$('#devicedetails').append($(txtTitle));
```

Full code below:

```
function getDeviceDetails() {
  var txtTitle = "";
  var txtOverview = "";
  var txtAccessories = "";
  var txtDevicetype = "";
  var txtTypicalDeviceUsage ="";
  var txtKnownSystemIssues ="";
  var txtLifeCycles = "";
  var tempLCS2 = "";

  var query = "http://collaboration-dev.xxx.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?$expand=LifeCycleStatus&$filter=Id eq " + window.DeviceId + "";
  var call = $.ajax({
    url: query,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    }       
  });
  call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
      var tempID = item.Id;
      var tempTitle = item.Title;

      var LifeCycleStart = item.DeviceAvailableFrom;
      var LifeCycleStatus = item.LifeCycleStatusValue;
      var DeviceOverView = item.Description;
      var AccessDetails = item.Accessories;
      var DeviceKind = item.Devicetype;
      var Usage = item.TypicalUsage;
      //var KnownSystem = item.KnownSystemIssues

      txtTitle = "<p>" + LifeCycleStart + "</p>       <p>" + 
        LifeCycleStatus + "</p>";
        txtOverview = "<p>" + DeviceOverView + "</p>";
        txtAccessories = "<p>" + AccessDetails + "</p>";  
        txtDevicetype = "<p>" + DeviceKind  + "</p>";
        txtTypicalDeviceUsage = "<p>" + Usage + "</p>"; 
    });

    $('#devicedetails').append($(txtTitle));  
    $('#deviceoverview').append($(txtOverview));
    $('#devicekind').append(txtDevicetype);
    $('#deviceacc').append(txtAccessories);
    $('#deviceuse').append(txtTypicalDeviceUsage);

  });

  call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
  });
}
```

Comment: Does the server returns `'/Date(1494460800000)/'`? Do you need to format it in `DD/MM/YYYY` format? What you tried so far? I think that `moment(/Date(1494460800000)/).format('DD/MM/YYYY')` should work, see [moment parsing > ASP.NET JSON Date](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/).

Comment: Ideally DD/MM/YYYY. 

Tried a few things, including:

var LifeCycleStart = new Date(item.DeviceAvailableFrom);
var wrapper = moment(wrapper).format("DD-MM-YY");

Everything I try seems to knock the rest of the results out

Answer (score 2):

Momentjs can parse string like `'/Date(1494460800000)/'` as stated in the [ASP.NET JSON Date](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/asp-net-json-date/) section of the parsing doc.

In your case you can do something like:

```
var LifeCycleStart = moment(item.DeviceAvailableFrom).format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

using [`format`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to convert moment object to string.

Comment: That does make sense, when I use that line it knocks out the rest of the results, so everything under Device Details and Specifications disappears